# Need help scheduling my compute engine to start at a certain time

Tags: cron, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need someone who can help me script and config my server to where my compute engine vm can boot up Monday - Saturday 7Am in the morning all the time.

If someone can help or guide me, i will really appreciate it.
I only know the most basic scripting language.
I am also willing to pay if that's the only option.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a way to initiate API commands to stop/start your GCE instance. The simplest way to do this is probably to use the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/), specifically:

- `gcloud compute instances start [names]` to start virtual machine instance(s)
- `gcloud compute instances stop [names]` to stop virtual machine instance(s)

Next, you need a way to run these commands on a schedule, e.g. to start your VM(s) at 7am Monday through Saturday. You'll need another computer (or service, for example [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine)) to do this. If you have a computer that runs 24x7 (e.g. your home laptop, or another cloud VM) then you can use `cron` or its equivalent to do this scheduling.